# SQL get records from specific day

Tags: sql

i am looking to only get records from exactly 3 days ago, not the records from now and as far back as 3 days ago... i only want records for that 24hour period and when i use the > its selecting everything from now until then

this is my query

```
SELECT user_id, nickname, user_email,  date_of_register, verification_code, user_photo_url FROM `tbl_users` WHERE verified='N' AND date_of_register > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)  ORDER BY date_of_register ASC
```

column date_of_register is `date time` and this is the format

```
2016-08-26 08:57:52
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Tag the proper RDBMS first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare dates instead of date and time, CAST your `date_of_register` as `DATE` only.

```
WHERE verified='N' AND 
      CAST( date_of_register AS DATE) = CAST(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS DATE)
```

Comment: In SQL server, this query prevents use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$date = "2016-08-26";
    SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `verified`='N' AND `date_of_register` = '{$date}' ORDER BY `date_of_register` ASC
```

Setting a variable of $date will always be the better way as it can be quicker to search rather than routing through numerous lines of code to find your query.

Rather than selecting a set few, why not just SELECT * (all) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to match date and ignore time to get result
use `DATE(date_of_register)` to get record from 3 days

```
SELECT user_id, nickname, user_email,  date_of_register, verification_code, user_photo_url FROM `tbl_users` WHERE verified='N' AND DATE(date_of_register) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)  ORDER BY date_of_register ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as the current accepted solution would prevent indexes from working on the date_of_register field.

```
set @date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)

SELECT user_id, nickname, user_email,  date_of_register, verification_code, user_photo_url
FROM `tbl_users`
WHERE verified='N'
AND date_of_register > @date
AND date_of_register < DATE_ADD(@date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY date_of_register ASC
```